# Apache Cxf publishing services

Tags: web-services, cxf

I am working on demo project in apache CXF, Every example in the internet is show to publish the service using spring configuration file.

Is there any way to publish the services in simple web project i.e Jsp/Servlets .

What I am think is to publish the Services using following code in servletContext.xml

```
HelloWorldImpl implementor = new HelloWorldImpl();
JaxWsServerFactoryBean svrFactory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
svrFactory.setServiceClass(HelloWorld.class);
svrFactory.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/helloWorld");
svrFactory.setServiceBean(implementor);
svrFactory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
svrFactory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
svrFactory.create();
```

Is this the right way?

Please throw some light.

Regards
Raman

Answer (score 0):

by using jax ws endpoint you can do this.

```html
<jaxws:endpoint id="queryAssetService" implementor="#queryAssetImpl"
  address="/services/queryAsset" xmlns:tns="namespace"
  serviceName="tns:serviceName">
  <jaxws:features>
   <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
  </jaxws:features>
 </jaxws:endpoint>
```